# Do you think Thead.sleep() is a good approach in Service?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, handle

I have a service as `MyService`. In my service, I have a global variable: `value` which is controled by a function `control_Value()`. The function used to control the value of varialbe `value` as follows rules:

> The time when calling the function is called initial time. At intial time, the value is set as  `One`. After 3 seconds from initial time, the value is set to `Zero`. The value will maintain `Zero` until the function is called again.

Based on the rule above, I wrote the `control_Value()` as follows:

```
public void control_Value()(){
   value="One";
   try{
       Thread.sleep(3000);
       value="Zero";
   }
   catch{}
}
```

Do you think Thead.sleep(3000) is a good approach? If not, please give me a better solution. Note that, the above function worked well.

This is my service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
  String value=null;
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          //TODO do something useful

          return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
    return null;
  }
  @Subscribe
  public void onSMSContentReceived(OnSMSReceiverEvent event) {
      control_Value();
  }
}
```

Update: The `onSMSContentReceived` is called automatically when a SMS come to phone.

This is solution using  countdown timer from suggestion of TGMCians

```
//Global variable
private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
//
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(mCountDownTimer!=null){
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    super.onDestroy();
}  
public void control_Value()(){

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        value="One";
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // Your stuff
        value="Zero";
    }
  };
  mCountDownTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: _"Do you think Thead.sleep(3000) is a good approach?"_ No. You're blocking the main thread in this case. AFAIK, you'll get ANR if you sleep for longer than 5 sec.

Comment: Thanks Onik. What is your suggestion? The above function is used as follow scenario: " when function is called. The `value` will be `One` within 3 seconds, after that the `value` is reset to `Zero`"

Comment: It depends on whether `onStartCommand()` can return until `value` = 0 or not. If `value` can be changed asynchronously then maybe [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) would be a good fit. If not, I guess a loop checking the difference between the start and current time would be enough. Or use Java synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: For simplification, I just call the function `controlValue()` in `onStartCommand()` in my example. In real case, I call the funtion in a BroacastReceiver of SMS. Hence, I think it will be independent with return value of `onStartCommand()`. Based on this, i think the second solution may good. Is it right?

Comment: I updated it to make it in real case. You do not need consider the `onStartCommand()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you think Thead.sleep(3000) is a good approach?

Never. Service run on application main thread without UI. Application will prompt ANR message in case you hold application main thread for certain seconds.

> What to do

If you want to perform operation after certain seconds, then you can use `CountDownTimer` in your service which has methods `onTick` & `onFinish` where `onTick` hits on regular interval and `onFinish` hits when time is up.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question 1 mins ago. Could you check it? I move the `controValue()` function to another function which is called when a Broadcast received as SMS

Comment: This is also OK if your service is running until `onSMSContentReceived` is invoked.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the CounterDown Timer method. It looked well. But I am woory about cancel and intial it. For example, if I use it in the `controlValue` function, it looks call CounterDown Timer whenever the `controlValue` is called. For example, I have three incoming SMS, then it will call `controlValue` three times without cancel. (Because I think cancel is call in onDestroy())

Comment: `onFinish` will be called once after X seconds, there you need to call `controlValue`

Comment: I updated my solution in my question based on your suggestion. Could you verify it?

Comment: seems OK, go ahead!

Comment: Thank you for good solution. Is it fine if I call the `mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000)` on `controlValue()` function which is called many time in the service (i.e. many SMS comming), but cancel only one time on onDestroy()?